# Can continuous observation freeze a quantum system?

Tags: quantum-mechanics, wavefunction

By continually observing a quantum system, is it true that this would prevent the wavefunction from evolving, effectively freezing the system into one particular state?

Comment: Reading assignment: *"quantum Zeno effect"*.

Comment: Request for clarification: We routinely observe the positions of macroscopic objects continuously, yet they still move around. These are quantum systems, insofar as they are made of molecules that obey the laws of quantum physics. Are you asking if there are examples where we *can* freeze something by continually observing it in a particular way, and why that doesn't happen with everyday observations of everyday objects?

Comment: @ChiralAnomaly No, I am asking if a quantum system can be forced into a particular steady state by repeated observations. I know that decoherence prevents the same effect in the macroscopic world.